# Dynamic Array Operations

Tags: c++, arrays, class, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation

Even though I passed array by reference the array is initialised to zero every time I insert element to array.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class ArrayOperations{
    public : 
        void insertInArray(int*& arr , int& arr_size);

        void displayArray(int*& arr , int& arr_size){
            cout<<"Elements of Array are : ";
            for(int i=0;i<arr_size;i++)
                cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
            cout<<endl;
        }
};

class InsertOperations : public ArrayOperations{
    public : 
        virtual void insertAtBeginning(int*& arr,int& arr_size,int val){
            arr = new int[arr_size++];
            for(int i=arr_size;i>0;i--)
                arr[i] = arr[i-1];
            arr[0] = val;
        }
};

void ArrayOperations :: insertInArray(int*& arr,int& arr_size){
    int val;
    cout<<"Enter Value to be Inserted : ";
    cin>>val;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Insert At Beginning"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Insert At Last"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Insert at K-th Position"<<endl<<endl;
    int choice;
    cout<<"Enter your choice : ";
    cin>>choice;
    InsertOperations io;
    switch(choice){
        case 1 :
            io.insertAtBeginning(arr,arr_size,val);
            break;
        default :
            cout<<"Enter A Valid Choice !!"<<endl;
            break;
    }
};

void displayMenu(){
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"==================Menu===================="<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Insert Element in Array"<<endl;
    cout<<"4. Display all Elements of Array"<<endl;
    cout<<"5. Exit"<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<endl;
}

int main(){
    int *arr;
    int arr_size=0;
    while(1){
        ArrayOperations ao;
        displayMenu();
        int choice;
        cout<<"Enter your choice : ";
        cin>>choice;
        if(choice==5)
            break;
        switch(choice){
            case 2 : 
                ao.insertInArray(arr,arr_size);
                break;
            case 4 :
                ao.displayArray(arr,arr_size);
                break;
            default :
                cout<<"Enter Valid Choice!"<<endl;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output is shown like : `5 0` after inserting element two times. Means previous value is reseted to 0 again and again.
Can anyone tell me whats the issue?
Also tell me where I'm going wrong. My program is compiling successfully only the issue is with insertion process.

Comment: 1. You did not pass an array by reference. You passed a pointer by reference. That pointer pointed to the first element of a dynamically allocated array. 2. `arr = new int[arr_size++];` made it forget everything and point to a completely new array. The old array is gone forever. 3.`arr[i] = arr[i-1];` manipulates the new array. Perhaps you wanted to copy values from the old array, but at this point the old array is not accessible.

Comment: Recommendation: back up the code and strip out al of the menu stuff. hardcode the inputs. You'll be able to debug faster.